# Get old value when setting a new one in a setter (javascript)

Tags: javascript, setter, getter

I'm trying to get the old value of the *hoveredElement*-attribute before changing it, but can't get it to work. When trying to log it, it shows always an empty object, eventhough I'm changing it (the program runs as expected, but I need the old value to improve it).

```
    let hoverEvent = {
      _hoveredElement: {},
      oldHoveredElement: {},
      _listener: function(val) {},
      set hoveredElement(val) {
          this._listener(val);
      },
      get hoveredElement() {
          return this._hoveredElement;
      },
      registerListener: function(listener) {
          this.oldHoveredElement = this._hoveredElement // ?
          this._listener = listener;
      }
    }

hoverEvent.registerListener(function(val) {

    console.log("Someone changed the value of hoveredElement to ", val); // works fine
    console.log("from ", this.oldHoveredElement); // empty object
...
}
```

I tried it with a new attribute *oldHoveredElement* and to set it to the current value in the *registerListener* but it doesn't work that way ( the line with the question marik)

Comment: I don't see that you set `_hoveredElement` or `oldHoveredElement` anywhere in the `set` function. So why should it be different to `{}`?

Comment: `oldHoveredElement` is set in the `registerListener` ( that's what I tried)
here's an example
https://codepen.io/issabln/pen/xxbqKRb

Comment: But you don't set `_hoveredElement` anywhere, so `_hoveredElement` will always be `{}`.

Comment: I think the problem is in your set hhoveredElement(val) since you actually don't update the _hoveredElement

Comment: yeah you're right. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles on the same problem, here's my solution

```
let hoverEvent = {
  oldHoveredElement : {},
  _hoveredElement: {},
  _listener: function(val) {},
  set hoveredElement(val) {
    this.oldHoveredElement = this._hoveredElement;
   this._hoveredElement = val;
    this._listener(val);
  },
  get hoveredElement() {
      return this._hoveredElement;
  },
  registerListener: function(listener) {
      this._listener = listener;
  }
}

hoverEvent.registerListener(function(val) {

console.log("Someone changed the value of hoveredElement to ", val); // works fine
console.log("from ", this.oldHoveredElement); // empty object
})
hoverEvent.hoveredElement= {"test":1}
hoverEvent.hoveredElement= {"test":2}
hoverEvent.hoveredElement= {"test":3}
```